# Copy and rename an existing Visual Studio Project

Tags: visual-studio

I copied an existing working Visual Studio project instead of creating a new one from scratch.

This way, i will avoid to import the references and the dependencies. 
After copying the folder, i renamed the folder to Project2, the `.sln` and the `.csproj` to Project2 as well.

Now when i run the copied project in Visual Studio, it runs my old project! why? do i need to modify something else ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at the "Folder Path" in the `Project -> Properties -> General` ?

Comment: My folder path point to the right folder. But it's weird because this morning i runned the project again and it runs the right one ! There's a cache or something in visual Studio ? how come sometimes it run the old project and sometimes it runs the old one ?

Comment: if you found it helpful, please consider an upvote or accepting the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain settings that bind to your project's solution (cached settings/files). There are ways to check this cache and clear it, but before that I would try these things:

1. Make sure that the `Project -> Properties -> General -> Path` is the right path.
2. Closing all open instances of Visual Studio can often help encourage settings-reset as well.
3. Often times, simply cleaning or rebuilding the project will correct all incorrect cache settings.
4. Delete your `bin` folder.
5. You could also try changing the URL/Directory by navigating to `Project Properties -> Web`, and changing the URL that way.

For example, changing `http://localhost:3688/`

to `http://localhost:36881/`

6. If the above steps don't work, you can always look in either

> C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local
>   Settings\Temp\VWDWebCache

or possibly

> C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

to clear cache that way.

Comment: I changed the port of my URL and now it works, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This method works always, but follows it carefully:

First I recommend deleting both x64 directories (at the project directory and the directory with source code). Also the heavy and hidden .vs directory

(NOTE: the resulting project can be copied to Pendrive or send by email because has a lot of stuff less)

Then copy and paste the directory and change the name to the new one.
Then change the name of project.sln
Then at the right of the project in the Solution Explorer window change manually the project name and also the solution name by clicking on its name with right mouse button. Then compile.